# Can not change or remove logs from project

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing a weird issue. I inserted some logs just like below:

`log('whatever messager you want');`

Now, no matter if I comment them or change the message inside them, nothing changes. Thay remain there the way I set it the first time. It happens in both VSCode and Android Studio.

**I already tried:**

1. deleting and installing the app again.
2. reload vscode window
3. close and reopen vscode
4. restart windows

Nothing worked for me.

Comment: If reinstalling the app doesn't cause a change you happen maybe you are not building the app you think you are building?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run

```
flutter clean
```

in your project directory?

Comment: It really worked. The logs are updated, but if I don't use this ```flutter clean``` command before every single relaunch of the app to the emulator, it doesn't updates changes. May this be a bug?

Comment: It may be a bug. Do you use any code generation packages?

Comment: No, if something is generating code in this app it would be the GetIt lib for dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `Ctrl + Shift + B` was displaying `No build task to run found` and `ctrl + F5` wasn't updating my code changes when using VSCode.

The solution I found was to migrate to Android Studio. I relaunched the emulator from Android Studio and the `Run` button updates the app correctly.